SSH on an EC2 instance Could not resolve hostname
I have spun up an Ubuntu EC2 instance and I need to ssh from it to another non-aws server but I'm having DNS or hostname resolution issues. I have enabled both DNS hostnames and DNS resolution on the VPC. Note that all of this works fine on my local machine so it doesn't not seem to be an issue with the non-aws server.
ubuntu@i:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=6.06 ms

ubuntu@i:~$ ping stream.test.northwestmedia.com
ping: stream.test.northwestmedia.com: Name or service not known

ubuntu@i:~$ ping 169.45.82.189
PING 169.45.82.189 (169.45.82.189) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.45.82.189: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=23.8 ms

ubuntu@i:~$ ssh jim@stream.test.northwestmedia.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname stream.test.northwestmedia.com: Name or service not known

ubuntu@i:~$ ssh jim@169.45.82.189
ssh: connect to host 169.45.82.189 port 22: No route to host

ubuntu@i:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.217.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sea09s29-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.217.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.28 ms

ubuntu@i:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=9.76 ms

[Update]
I sorted out my local hosts file which was causing confusion. The hostname is actually stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com. I can now ping it from the EC2 but I still can't ssh to it for some reason.
ubuntu@i:~$ ping stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com
PING stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com (169.45.82.189) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bd.52.2da9.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (169.45.82.189): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=24.0 ms

ubuntu@i:~$ ssh jim@stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com
ssh: connect to host stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com port 22: No route to host

ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-179:~$ ssh -v jim@169.45.82.189
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 169.45.82.189 [169.45.82.189] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 169.45.82.189 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 169.45.82.189 port 22: No route to host

[Update]
Here is a traceroute to the IP:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-179:~$ traceroute -n 169.45.82.189
traceroute to 169.45.82.189 (169.45.82.189), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * 244.5.0.101  5.154 ms 244.5.0.185  4.761 ms
 2  108.166.236.44  1.579 ms 240.3.212.39  1.543 ms 240.0.120.7  1.530 ms
 3  242.0.10.197  3.558 ms 100.66.11.170  15.448 ms 240.1.228.12  5.880 ms
 4  240.1.228.16  5.862 ms 241.0.2.65  1.431 ms 240.1.228.16  7.682 ms
 5  150.222.214.180  8.205 ms 240.1.228.16  7.723 ms  7.832 ms
 6  240.1.228.12  7.742 ms 206.81.80.140  9.299 ms 242.0.10.69  1.959 ms
 7  206.81.80.140  9.309 ms 240.1.228.16  7.604 ms 169.45.18.122  10.821 ms
 8  169.45.18.122  10.790 ms 169.45.18.1  23.931 ms 240.1.228.16  7.657 ms
 9  50.97.17.227  23.994 ms 50.97.17.225  21.862 ms 169.45.18.1  24.154 ms
10  206.81.80.140  10.597 ms 169.45.18.122  10.691 ms  8.868 ms
11  169.45.82.189  23.844 ms !X 169.45.18.1  22.112 ms  24.008 ms


The host stream.test.northwestmedia.com can't be resolved via internet. Check on your machine if you have some record in hosts file.
About ssh seems like the post 22 is filtered on this host. Try to login via kind of web console if exist. Or contact support.

The only thing in the hosts file  (on the aws server) is 127.0.0.1 localhost. Not sure what you mean by "unreachable." If I ping stream.test.northwestmedia.com from my desktop, it is reachable and it's IP is 169.45.82.189.

@Rooster242, in hosts file of your desktop, because this is the place where you can resolve the hostname.

Ah, good catch. I inherited this desktop from a previous employee who had a bunch of goofy entries in the hosts file. The real hostname is actually stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com. However, on the ec2 instance, I can now ping stream.test.fosterparentcollege.com but still can not ssh to it. Can't ssh to the IP either. I'll update the question.

@Rooster242, this is another question. Please create new one.

Same question/problem, different hostname.

@Rooster242, the main problem on the begin was resolving the hostname. The second is routing. Add in the question at lease ssh -v user@host.....

Updated with an ssh -v.

@Rooster242, try traceroute -n 169.45.82.189

Updated question with traceroute.

@Rooster242, see my updated answer

Can you elaborated on what you mean by filtered? I tried spinning up a new EC2, default everything, and still can't ssh in it.

@Rooster242, this can be "function" of the provider. Or maybe you should enable somewhere explicitly the ssh access.

I appreciate the advice @Romeo Ninov. The provider is AWS. It's an EC2 instance.

@Rooster242, in AWS console you should add network rule or security group to enable ssh for your IP or IP range (port 22)
